# ASP.NET Razor - Unencoding Value

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am working on a form using the new Razor view engine, and am having an issue with a form field having an encoded value. I have the following code on my form:

```
<form id="handout" method="post" class="padded_form" enctype="multipart/form-data"
    action="@Url.Remarketing().HandoutNew(Model.Inspection.InspectionId, Request.QueryString[QueryStringParamConstants.RedirectURL])">
    <h2>Handout Options</h2>
    <li>
        @Html.Label("handout.Price", "Price")
        @Html.TextBox("handout.Price", Model.Handout.Price)
    </li>
```

where price is a decimal value. If I enter say "1,000" on the form, the value posted is: "&handout.Price=1%2c000" and the Price property on my entity does not get populated.

Is there a way to not encode this value when the form is posted?

Thanks.

Comment: The problem is the `,`, not the `%2c`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to use client-side javascript to normalize the value an remove any formatting characters.

Alternatively you could implement your own `IValueProvider` that could perform the conversion on the server before the model is databound.

Comment: Thank you. That's kind of what I expected.